# Unknown Minifig Accessory (chrome silver/pearl gold)

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I got a bunch of these in a bulk bin and cannot figure out what they are. It is possible they are not lego itself as I cannot find a lego logo on it anywhere.

Anyone know what they are?

[image: Unknown Tools]

Comment: I cannot id this as LEGO. There's also no such item in Chrome Silver [BL]. Probably something from clone brands. One question though - does the bar end fit in minifigure's arm?